# Show that a set is not Jordan measurable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I have a set consisting of the points of a countably infinite, non-constant sequence on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that this isn't Jordan measurable, but I am not quite sure how to approach it.

I know that the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem applies so I know that there is a convergent subsequence. My approach is to try to show that boundary of the set does not have volume $0$ in order to show that the set is not Jordan measurable. However, I am not quite sure how to use the fact that it has convergent subsequence.

Comment: It seems to me that if $a_n$ converges, then the Jordan measure of $\{a_n\}$ is zero.

Comment: This isn't true in general. The points of the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are countable and non-constant yet this set is Jordan measurable.

Comment: If you have a sequence such that the closure of the set  of its terms has non-empty interior then the set cosisting of terms of this sequence is not Jordan measurable. Its follows from the fact that in this case the bounduary of this sets has not measure zero.

Comment: In case you missed it, the importance of user156205's remark is that the result does not follow from any information you've given. It cannot be shown from that information alone. If you know anything more about this sequence, it is that additional information that would make it not Jordan measurable. Do you have additional information about this sequence?